# Looking for a translation of a German expression "mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit"

Tags: translation, german

In German language you use an expression *mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit* to say that you are almost one hundred percent sure/certain.

A particularity of that expression is that it has a subtility that I think comes from probability/mathematics; you say that you are not one hundred percent sure, but you can come arbitrarily close to certainty.
The expression also can make someone smile and/or shows a little bit of sophistication in the usage of the German language despite it's somewhat confusing meaning.
A probably wrong but literal translation could be something like *with probability bordering/verging on certainty*.

I use the expressions *almost certain*, *very sure*, *pretty sure*, etc. in this case, but I wonder....

In English language there is an expression that can come very close to the German expression?

Comment: In English we have to put participle clauses like this *after* the nominal they modify. Translated literally this is  *with a probability bordering/verging on certainty*";  that's perfectly idiomatic and actually fairly common. I found about 50 instances in Google Books -- though I have to admit, a lot of those are translations from German!

Comment: 99 and 44/100ths percent pure. Started as a tag phrase for an American soap company.

Comment: I got an answer on [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/296534/121336). *with confidence bordering on certainty* seems to be an acceptable expression and used in English language.

Answer (score 1):

The closest phrase that comes to mind comes from law - the phrase:

**"Beyond a reasonable doubt"**

or the more poetic, but similar,

**"Beyond a shadow of a doubt"**.

While neither would exactly bring a smile to someone's face, they sound very natural and familiar to a native speaker and carry a formal, sophisticated tone.